# Add event handler on bot message Telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, telethon

I wanna add a event handler to work with the client message:

```
client = TelegramClient(session_name,api_id,api_hash)

# Event I wanna Run 
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=False,func=lambda p:p.is_private))
async def test(event):
    return True

# Message I wanna send to run the event
async def main():
    await client.send_message('me','Test')

client.start()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

I want the `test()` to run when the client send a message to **its self**

Its Ok when I send message to 'me' through another client
but the event doesnt run when I send message as the same client

Comment: a session indeed won't receive updates for requests that it issued itself

Comment: Ok thanks, I tought maybe there is a option to make it receive updates